# Incorrect GestureDetector arguments

Tags: flutter, dart, gesture, fluttermap

so i have a `GestureDetector` where if i scale it will increase or decrease the values ,The values are latitude and longitude, Next if i pan it will again do the same for latitude and longitude,

Please note these values are the values of image overlay on `flutter_map`

if I use either `onScaleUpdate` or `onPanUpdate`  it works fine, but if i use both i get the error

```
The following assertion was thrown building LayoutBuilder:
Incorrect GestureDetector arguments.

Having both a pan gesture recognizer and a scale gesture recognizer is redundant; scale is a superset of pan.

Just use the scale gesture recognizer.
```

I need the specific latitude and longitude values , there are other values that will use `scale` or `offset` but this is not what i want as eventually i will need to convert those to latitude and longitude.

in short, how can use scale and pan at the same time in my gesture detector

this is the code

```dart
Positioned(
    top: 250,
    right: 10,
    child: GestureDetector(
        onScaleUpdate: (details) {
            double scaleFactor = details.scale;
            if (scaleFactor > 1) {
                topL[chosenPlate] !.latitude += tolerance;
                botL[chosenPlate] !.latitude -= tolerance;
                botR[chosenPlate] !.latitude -= tolerance;
                topL[chosenPlate] !.longitude -= tolerance;
                botL[chosenPlate] !.longitude -= tolerance;
                botR[chosenPlate] !.longitude += tolerance;
            } else if (scaleFactor < 1) {
                topL[chosenPlate] !.latitude -= tolerance;
                topL[chosenPlate] !.longitude -= tolerance;
                botL[chosenPlate] !.latitude += tolerance;
                botL[chosenPlate] !.longitude -= tolerance;
                botR[chosenPlate] !.latitude += tolerance;
                botR[chosenPlate] !.longitude += tolerance;
            }
        },
        onPanUpdate: (details) {
            if (details.delta.dx < 0) {
                setState(() {
                    topL[chosenPlate] !.longitude -= tolerance;
                    botL[chosenPlate] !.longitude -= tolerance;
                    botR[chosenPlate] !.longitude -= tolerance;
                });
            } else if (details.delta.dx > 0) {
                setState(() {
                    topL[chosenPlate] !.longitude += tolerance;
                    botL[chosenPlate] !.longitude += tolerance;
                    botR[chosenPlate] !.longitude += tolerance;
                });
            } else if (details.delta.dy < 0) {
                setState(() {
                    topL[chosenPlate] !.latitude += tolerance;
                    botL[chosenPlate] !.latitude += tolerance;
                    botR[chosenPlate] !.latitude += tolerance;
                });
            } else if (details.delta.dy > 0) {
                setState(() {
                    topL[chosenPlate] !.latitude -= tolerance;
                    botL[chosenPlate] !.latitude -= tolerance;
                    botR[chosenPlate] !.latitude -= tolerance;
                });
            }
        },
        child: Container(
            height: 20. h,
            width: 30. w,
            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 233, 176, 176),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: as the error says you have to remove `onPanUpdate` and make your logic based on `onScaleUpdate` only

Comment: @pskink ofcourse! i could do that, if i choose to keep onPanUpdate i loose the ability to zoom in or out (scale) , if i choose to keep `onScaleUpdate` i loose the ability to pan left or right, i can choose only one to get rid of the error but i need all the functionality, hence the question.

Comment: no, you can get all the data you need from [ScaleUpdateDetails](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/ScaleUpdateDetails-class.html) - they say it clearly in the error message: "scale is a superset of pan"

Comment: Yes sir! Then how do u get the data? What is the workaround? That is basically my question. Apologies if my question isn't clear enough.

Comment: check all the properties of `ScaleUpdateDetails` (the link above) - it's jut few of them (if the docs are not clear enough just  `print` them in your callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the message says, you need to use the `onScaleUpdate` to handle the panning as well. I believe `details.focalPointDelta` can be used in the `onScaleUpdate` instead of the `details.delta` in `onPanUpdate`, so it will be:

```
    onScaleUpdate: (details) {
        double scaleFactor = details.scale;
        if (scaleFactor > 1) {
            topL[chosenPlate] !.latitude += tolerance;
            botL[chosenPlate] !.latitude -= tolerance;
            botR[chosenPlate] !.latitude -= tolerance;
            topL[chosenPlate] !.longitude -= tolerance;
            botL[chosenPlate] !.longitude -= tolerance;
            botR[chosenPlate] !.longitude += tolerance;
        } else if (scaleFactor < 1) {
            topL[chosenPlate] !.latitude -= tolerance;
            topL[chosenPlate] !.longitude -= tolerance;
            botL[chosenPlate] !.latitude += tolerance;
            botL[chosenPlate] !.longitude -= tolerance;
            botR[chosenPlate] !.latitude += tolerance;
            botR[chosenPlate] !.longitude += tolerance;
        }

        if (details.focalPointDelta.dx < 0) {
            setState(() {
                topL[chosenPlate] !.longitude -= tolerance;
                botL[chosenPlate] !.longitude -= tolerance;
                botR[chosenPlate] !.longitude -= tolerance;
            });
        } else if (details.focalPointDelta.dx > 0) {
            setState(() {
                topL[chosenPlate] !.longitude += tolerance;
                botL[chosenPlate] !.longitude += tolerance;
                botR[chosenPlate] !.longitude += tolerance;
            });
        } else if (details.focalPointDelta.dy < 0) {
            setState(() {
                topL[chosenPlate] !.latitude += tolerance;
                botL[chosenPlate] !.latitude += tolerance;
                botR[chosenPlate] !.latitude += tolerance;
            });
        } else if (details.focalPointDelta.dy > 0) {
            setState(() {
                topL[chosenPlate] !.latitude -= tolerance;
                botL[chosenPlate] !.latitude -= tolerance;
                botR[chosenPlate] !.latitude -= tolerance;
            });
        }
    },
```